# Properties.Settings.Save() не сохраняет настройки

Tags: c#

Создал коллекцю Hashtable в Properties -> Settings
сохраняю так

```
 private static void DisplayCompanyData(Type t)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation == null)
            // Имена плагинов которые мы подлючили
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation = new Hashtablу();
        // Получить данные [CompanyInfo]
        var companyInfo = from ci in t.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                          where (ci.GetType() == typeof(CompanyInfoAttribute))
                          select ci;

        foreach (CompanyInfoAttribute c in companyInfo) {
            // Коллекция ключ-значение
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation.Add(PLUGIN_NAME, c.PluginName);          
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation.Add(DISPLAY_PLUGIN_NAME, c.DisplayPluginName);
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation.Add(PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION, c.PluginDescription);
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation.Add(AUTHOR, c.Author);
            Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation.Add(VERSION, c.Version);
        }    

        // Сохраняем настройки программы
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Помимо этой коллекции есть еще переменные, так вот они сохраняются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить атрибут [`SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.configuration.settingsserializeas(v=vs.110).aspx) к свойству `pluginInformation` в файле `Settings.Designer.cs`:

```
[global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs(global::System.Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Binary)]
public Hashtable pluginInformation
{
    ...
}
```

Это значение атрибута позволяет сериализовывать произвольные объекты в файл настроек.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, вы не забыти, что сохраняются только настройки из области User, а настройки из Application - ReadOnly?

Ни разу не сталкивался с сохранением настроек, но обычно такое случается из-за того, что Settings не может определить факт изменений внутри Hashtable, поскольку ссылка-то осталась та же самая!

Попробуйте применить "подергивание":

```
Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation = Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation;
```

Если не помогает, попробуйте создавать новую хеш-таблицу при каждом изменении:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation = new Hashtable(Properties.Settings.Default.pluginInformation);
```

Comment: не помогает, подскажите где хранятся эти настройки?